# Why are transcendental functions of large numbers inaccurate on computers?

Tags: floating-point, numerical-analysis, numerical-algorithms, rounding

For instance, why is it hard to accurately compute sin(1e99)? I suspect it has something to do with rounding error.

Comment: `log(1e99)` is fairly simple though ;)

Comment: I don't agree with the title, as this isn't true for all transcendental functions (f.i. the logarithm and exponential have no such issue). It's probably more characteristic of oscillating functions.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I'd argue that the problem is fairly general. The logarithm is in fact the main exception, as the usual floating-point representation explicitly stores an exponent. And `exp(x)` can be approximated by `exp(x/2) ^ 2`. That said, any function that _doesn't_ oscillate tends to have an asymptote or go to infinity, both of which make the implementation for large arguments trivial.

Answer (score 6):

There's nothing fundamentally hard about computing $\sin(10^{99})$.  You simply compute $x = 10^{99} \bmod 2\pi$, then compute $\sin(x)$.  (Why is this valid?  It's because $\sin(x)=\sin(y)$ if $x\equiv y \pmod{2\pi}$.)  It's not too hard to compute $x$ if you use a numerical representation that has enough digits of precision, and then to compute $\sin(x)$ using standard methods.

However, a standard `double` won't have enough precision to perform this computation.  It only has about 53 bits of precision; that's a lot less than the $99 \lg 10 \approx 329$ bits of precision you'd need to be able to distinguish $10^{99}$ from $10^{99}+1$. (A standard IEEE `float` cannot even represent values in excess of $3*10^{38}$). Of course, $\sin(10^{99})$ is *very* different from $\sin(10^{99}+1)$.  So, if you want to compute $\sin(10^{99})$, just stuffing $10^{99}$ into a `float` or `double` and then trying to invoke the $\sin(\cdot)$ function on that is not going to end well.

If you want to compute $x$ to at least $b$ bits of precision, you'll probably need a numerical representation that can represent $10^{99}$ to at least $329+b$ bits of precision (probably more than that, for intermediate values that arise during the modular reduction).  A `float` or `double` ain't gonna be enough for that.

Comment: Just as a random comment, dealing with $\sin (10^{99})$ correctly is one of the reasons why standard library implementations of these functions can be much slower than hand-rolled implementations.

Comment: @Pseudonym: It shouldn't be; good implementations tend to use different code paths for different inputs. The biggest difference as compared to hand-rolled implementations is probably how careful they are with the last few bits of precision on typical inputs.

Comment: Having implemented sin(x) myself (embedded platform), I can confirm sin(10^99) is easy. You need to check the exponent anyway, and for this case just return 0. The hard parts are around 2^24 (16 million) where the Least Significant Bit is in the order of π.

Comment: @MSalters "just return 0" -- are you claiming that $\sin(10^{99})=0$? That can't be correct, since $10^{99}$ isn't a multiple of $\pi$. If that's not what you're claiming, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: obviously standard floating-point implementations cannot compute $\sin(10^{99})$ with a single significant digit, as they are just unable to represent that number. Hence returning $0$ isn't worse than any other value.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: 10^99 isn't even exactly representable in double precision. The actual number passed to sin(x) will be a 53 bit approximation (so about 16 digits), approximately 1.8287798260516400 * 2^328. The rounding error there is about 0.00000000000000000003 * 2^238, which is far, far larger than π.

Comment: @MSalters OK but, in that case, the sine function doesn't know that its input was supposed to be $10^{99}$ so the algorithm `if input=10^99 return 0 else do something else` doesn't even make sense. What are you going to return for $1.8287798260516400 \times 2^{328}$?

Comment: @DavidRicherby: The actual implementation is `if input.exponent > 26 return 0.0`. When the possible rounding error exceeds the 2π period, the output is fully dependent on that unknown rounding error. 0 is simply the mean value of sin(x).

Comment: @MSalters, that's not computing the value of $\sin(10^{99})$.  $\sin(10^{99})$ is a mathematical expression with a well-defined value, and that value sure isn't $0$. You're trying to figure out what the `sin(.)` code should do when it pretty much knows that it can't compute the sine of its input accurately, due to floating point imprecision; that's a different matter. Normally comments are intended for suggestions for how to improve the answer or requests for clarification, and I don't quite see any improvement or clarification suggested in your comment.  Have I missed something?

Comment: @Hurkyl Not this case specifically, but cases like this. Many transcendental functions have high-quality approximations which work in "sensible" ranges, but you need special case when doing computations outside the sensible range. Your standard library must return a correct value for $\sin(10^{99})$, however most of the time, asking for the sine of that number is evidence of a bug in the program. Sometimes the call to sin is part of a larger formula where the range of sin is asymptotically negligible, e.g. the sinc function.

Answer (score 4):

Taking the sine of large numbers is a **numerically unstable** operation.

Considering an argument like $10^{99}$, you can get a completely different value of the sine by adding, say $1$ to it. Think that this is a relative change of $10^{-99}$ !

---

Indeed,
$$|\sin(a+1)-\sin(a)|=|2\sin(\frac12)\cos(a+\frac12)|>0.95|\sin(a+\frac12)|,$$

so that you can find arbitrarily tiny $\epsilon=\dfrac1a$ such that

$$|\sin(a(1+\epsilon))-\sin(a)|>0.5.$$